# Where condition not working in query builder left Join laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel

I am trying to convert a raw query to Laravel query builder.

```
SELECT
    i.item_name,
    i.item_code,
    i.reorder_qty,
    s.total_qty AS available_qty
FROM
    items i
LEFT JOIN stocks s ON
    i.id = s.item_id
WHERE
    i.reorder_qty IS NOT NULL
    AND i.reorder_qty >= s.total_qty
ORDER BY
    s.total_qty ASC;
```

The raw query works fine. I am trying to convert this query into Laravel query builder. But I am not getting expected result.

```
DB::table('items')
    ->leftJoin('stocks', function ($join) {
        $join->on('items.id', '=', 'stocks.item_id')
            ->where('items.reorder_qty', '>=', 'stocks.total_qty');
    })
    ->whereNotNull('items.reorder_qty')
    ->select('items.item_name', 'items.item_code', 'items.reorder_qty', 'stocks.total_qty')
    ->orderBy('stocks.total_qty', 'ASC')
    ->get();
```

I think the problem is my line

```
->where('items.reorder_qty', '>=', 'stocks.total_qty');
```

How am I able to add this condition in query builder.

Comment: Your raw query is errorneous. The condition part `AND i.reorder_qty >= s.total_qty` converts LEFT JOIN implicitly to INNER JOIN.

Comment: @Akina Then what will be the right way?

Comment: Either use INNER JOIN or move this condition from WHERE to ON clause - depends on the query logic. The ordering by right table column prefers the former choice.

Answer (score 0):

Your raw query under the hood working as an inner join.

If you want to get same result then you can do following query:

```
DB::table( 'items' )
->select( 'items.item_name', 'items.item_code', 'items.reorder_qty', 'stocks.total_qty' )
->join( 'stocks', 'items.id', '=', 'stocks.item_id' )
->whereNotNull( 'items.reorder_qty' )
->where( 'items.reorder_qty', '>=', 'stocks.total_qty' )
->orderBy( 'stocks.total_qty', 'ASC' )
->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

The working raw query -

```
SELECT
    i.item_name,
    i.item_code,
    i.reorder_qty,
    s.total_qty AS available_qty
FROM
    items i
JOIN stocks s ON i.id = s.item_id AND i.reorder_qty >= s.total_qty
WHERE
    i.reorder_qty IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY
    s.total_qty ASC;
```

And the working query builder

```
DB::table('items')
->join('stocks', function ($join) {
    $join->on('items.id', '=', 'stocks.item_id');
    $join->on('items.reorder_qty', '>=', 'stocks.total_qty');
})
->whereNotNull('items.reorder_qty')
->select('items.item_name', 'items.item_code', 'items.reorder_qty', 'stocks.total_qty as available_qty')
->orderBy('stocks.total_qty', 'ASC')
->get();
```